# how to inherit _action_done() method of stock.move.line in odoo v11

Tags: python, odoo-11

In the **stock.move.line** model of odoo v11 there is a method named **_action_done()** . I want to send some values with the lot info. For that I needed to use that method and wrote following:

First sample:

```
def _action_done(self):
    res = super(StockMoveLineExt, self)._action_done()
    for ml in self:
        if ml.lot_id and ml.date_expire:
            ml.lot_id.text_field = ml.text_field
    return res
```

Second sample:

```
def _action_done(self):
    for ml in self:
        if ml.lot_id and ml.date_expire:
            ml.lot_id.text_field = ml.text_field
    res = super(StockMoveLineExt, self)._action_done()
    return True
```

Now the purpose I intend to do is done by the first sample. But it creates ***serious problem*** in **stock.move**. Like- if I do a POS order/sale then the order picking remains in waiting state. But it should have gone to done stock. For internal transfers there are extra lines on the **stock.move.line** which is creating duplicate lines and needs to be deleted manually.

Now, I have overwritten the method by adding own needed codes. But I don't want this. What am I doing wrong? How to override this method?

Comment: Does some one found a solution fro this question? I'm not able to inherit from stock.move but order tables doesn't cause me any problems.

`
class StockMove(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.moves'

    created_stock_quotation_request_line_id = fields.Many2one(
        'stock.quotation.request',
        'Created Quotation Request',
        ondelete='set null', readonly=True, copy=False)`